# How to add files manually to SharePoint site collect in readonly mode?

Tags: 2010, site-collection, file-upload, read-only

We have a SharePoint2010 on HTTPS with only one site collection. All users will have readonly access to the documents therefore site collect is locked to readonly. But we would like the site administrator to add documents to the collection manually (by logging into the server if applicable) when required so that all users can view it.

**We do not want to add every user in read only mode.

My thoughts - site administrator can access the folder and add documents to it through the windows explorer on the server, but it does not work.

Please provide some insight into it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem that can be solved using the SharePoint permissions.

You'll need to give the user you want to upload documents contribute access.  The easiest way to do this is to add them into the Members group.

Add your other users to the Visitors group.  Note that you can do this using an AD group or using the All Authenticated Users group.  Be aware that this will give everyone with an account read only access.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the update. But in this approach, the contribute user can upload the documents directly using the browser. But we want to limit it and only do it manually or physically on the document library location. Any thoughts for the work around for that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by manually or physically. Can you expand on that?